# Trying to loop through progressbar.js animations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to countinually alternate between two cycles using progressbar.js. Nothing happens when I run this code, even though it works fine when I am not trying to repeat. Any suggestions?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  var timer = new ProgressBar.Circle('#progress', {
    easing: 'linear',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    trailWidth: 1,
    color: '#ff9900'
  });



 function loop() {
    timer.set(0);
    timer.setText('Work');
    timer.animate(1, {
      duration: 25000
    }, function() {
      timer.set(0);
      timer.setText('Break');
      timer.animate(1, {
        duration: 5000
      },loop);
    });

    loop(); 
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function loop() {
    timer.set(0);
    timer.setText('Work');
    timer.animate(1, {
      duration: 25000
    }, function() {
      timer.set(0);
      timer.setText('Break');
      timer.animate(1, {
        duration: 5000
      },loop);
    });

    loop(); //remove
  }
  loop();//add
```